# Gecko Select Element Set Selected without Submit

Tags: c#, html, geckofx

I'm using GeckoFx to click through a form on a webpage. 
There is a select element on the page of which I want to set the selected item.
When a normal user selects an element, an event is triggered showing a secondary select list. When I select using the GeckoFx library it doesn't do that.

Any ideas what I can do to make my selection trigger that event as well?

My Code

```
var enquiryTypeCombo = (GeckoSelectElement)document.GetElementById("enquiry_type");
enquiryTypeCombo.Value = _stepController.EnquiryType;
enquiryTypeCombo.Click();
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to trigger the event as well - so, for example, if your secondary select box is shown upon an 'onkeyup' event, try the following code

```
nsAStringBase eventType = (nsAStringBase)new nsAString("keyup");
                                var ev = browser.Document.CreateEvent("HTMLEvents");
                                ev.DomEvent.InitEvent(eventType, false, false);
                                enquiryTypeCombo.GetEventTarget().DispatchEvent(ev);
```

From my experience, the very 'click' does not trigger the events.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, will try that ! 
Click does nothing, you're right.

Comment: The KeyUp does nothing for my situation. 

If I browse to the webpage containing the control myself, it only updates the page if I select a new item in the dropdown list. 
If dropdown is selected and I press Up Down arrows, it doesn't update page, Space & Enter key do nothing either. 

So I need the DropDown Item-Selected-By-Mouse-or-something event ? 
Any Ideas?

Comment: Try the DocumentInspector in firefox - right click the select element, look at the source code - there should be a javascript event there - then look at the event name and try triggering it

Comment: That did the trick. It was the OnChange Event, which translates into


`nsAStringBase eventType = (nsAStringBase)new nsAString("change");
                                var ev = browser.Document.CreateEvent("HTMLEvents");
                                ev.DomEvent.InitEvent(eventType, false, false);
                                enquiryTypeCombo.GetEventTarget().DispatchEvent(ev);`

Thanks a bunch !

Comment: No problem, glad I could help - good luck with next challenges:)